# How to effectively run a background Processing and Logging of Data (Debian, Beaglebone Black)

Tags: c++, c, linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm looking for some help with an implementation problem I'm facing. I'm an experienced C/C++ programmer in embedded environments and RTOSs, but when it comes to linux I'm a newbie.

I have a beaglebone black running Debian. I need to log and process data from sensors connected to the I2C bus and the ADC. I have written the handler functions for collecting the data from the sensors connected, no problem there, they work fine. I want to implement (similar to a RTOS) a timer interrupt that can throw the process to my handler functions so they can do their things and I want this to run in the background. i.e. I don't want to tie up the shell or whatever so the user can do other things. I was reading that timer_create is a way do this within Debian, or using fork()-exec() but I thought I'd ask people experienced in Linux first before going down any particular path! Also, not 100% sure how to use either of these functions.

side-note: I know that timers etc. are not highly accurate in Linux unless you are implementing pre-emptive kernels or whatever, which is a whole other problem in itself, but the time constraints of this problem are somewhere near 10-50ms which is not extremely tight.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make a daemon process , just take this as a reference:

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/daemon.c

Comment: But is creating a daemon the correct way for this particular application? Is a daemon used in userspace or kernel space? Sorry I'm rather new to programming linux

Comment: in linux , a daemon is a ordinary process not  attached to a terminal, running in userspace.